# Track progress of dd command called using open3 in ruby

Tags: ruby, popen3

I am trying to monitor the progress of copying a raspberry-pi OS image to a microSD card. This is similar to [Kill a process called using open3 in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268454/kill-a-process-called-using-open3-in-ruby), except I'm not killing the process, I'm sending it a command for it to issue a progress message.

```
  
    rpath = device_path.gsub(/disk/, "rdisk")
    puts "\n\nCopying image to #{rpath}"

    if false
      stdout_err, status = Open3.capture2e( "sudo", "dd", "bs=1m", "if=#{source_path}", "of=#{rpath}" )
      puts stdout_err
    else
      cmd = "sudo dd bs=1m if=#{source_path} of=#{rpath}"
      Open3.popen2e(cmd) do |stdin, stdout_err, wait_thr|
        Thread.new do
          stdout_err.each {|l| puts l}
        end

        Thread.new do
          while true
            sleep 5
            if true
              Process.kill("INFO", wait_thr.pid)      #Tried INFO, SIGINFO, USR1, SIGUSR1
                                                      # all give:  `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
            else
              stdin.puts  20.chr      #Should send ^T -- has no effect, nothing to terminal during flash
            end
          end
        end

        wait_thr.value
      end
```

The first section (after 'if false') flashes the image using **Open3.capture2e**. This works, but of course issues no progress information.

The section after the 'else' flashes the image using **Open3.popen2e**. It also attempts to display progress by either issuing 'Process.kill("INFO", wait_thr.pid)', or by sending ^T (20.chr) to the stdin stream every 5 seconds.

The **Process.kill** line generates an "Operation not permitted" error. The **stdin.puts** line has no effect at all.

One other thing... While the popen2e process is flashing, hitting ctrl-T on the keyboard DOES generate a progress response. I just can't get it to do it programmatically.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `dd` have an optional progress bar, as seen [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/). Even so I think you'll want to rethink how you execute that shell command so that it thinks it's attached to a terminal. Easiest thing to do is fork/exec, like:

```
cmd = "sudo dd bs=1m if=#{source_path} of=#{rpath} status=progress"
fork do
    exec(cmd) # this replaces the forked process with the cmd, giving it direct access to your terminal
end

Process.wait() # waits for the child process to exit
```

If that's not an option you may want to look into other ways of getting unbuffered output, including just writing a bash script instead of a ruby one.

Comment: Unfortunately, MACOS does not support the 'status' feature. 
```
sol:~ sjf$ sudo dd bs=1m if=~/Desktop/buster.img of=/dev/rdisk status=progress
Password:
dd: unknown operand status
```

Comment: Ah. Well, maybe give [this](https://davejansen.com/dd-with-progress-indication-on-macos/) a shot, then.